# Formal definition on graph levels

Tags: graphs, dag

I'm looking for a formal definition of "graph levels" on a DAG. This example should illustrate what I mean by this.

The node 0 has no edges directed towards it, therefore this has level 0. Next is is 3 and 4 which will have level 1 and so on.

Level 0 : node 0

Level 1 : node 3, node 4

Level 2 : node 1, node 2

Level 3 : node 5

[image]

Comment: Given a source $s$, can you define the level $L_i = \{ v \mid d(s,v) = i \}$? In general, it makes little sense to say you want a formal definition of something, since you are free to make any kind of definitions you want. It depends on what you want to capture and do with the definition.

Comment: But does this definition have a formal name?

Comment: Its formal name is whatever you give it, like maybe a level structure.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not expressing myself clear. What I'm asking for is a mainstream name for the definition so that I can google on it.

Answer (score 3):

A DAG (or poset) is *ranked* or *graded* if it is possible to assign nodes a rank function $r$ such that if $(x,y)$ is a directed edge, $r(y) = r(x)+1$. We usually choose $r$ so that $\min r = 0$. See for example the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) on graded poset.

Comment: would be nice if you could apply the definition to the given sample graph. I guess $r(0) = 0, r(4) = 1, r(2) = 2$

Answer (score 2):

This is sometimes known as a [level structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_structure), and they come up in e.g., certain algorithmic applications.